# Deleting blank rows in a table with Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I want to create a macro to loop through a table and delete blank rows based on criteria found in columns B:E without deleting the second to last row of the table.

The second to last row of the table will always be empty in columns B:E so I want it to skip that row.

Here are the names of the columns of B, C, D, E

Client
Pipeline Stage (Select dropdown)
Forecast Close (Select dropdown)
Potential Opportunity

Here's what I have below but I am not sure how to modify it to the correct formatting.

```
Sub Delete_Table_Rows()

Dim tblrows As Range
Dim client As Long
Dim tbl As ListObjects
Dim ws As Worksheet

With Application
    .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    .ScreenUpdating = False

Set ws = Sheets(“sheet1”)
set tblrows = ws.worksheets("sheet1").Range(“table1, [client]").Value = ""

    For client = Selection.Rows.Count To 1 Step -1
        If WorksheetFunction.CountA(Selection.Rows(client)) = “” Then
            Selection.Rows(client).EntireRow.Delete
        End If
Next i
    .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    .ScreenUpdating = True
End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this...

```
Sub DeleteBlankRowsFromTable()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim tbl As ListObject
Dim i As Long, FirstRow As Long, LastRow As Long
Dim rng As Range
With Application
    .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    .ScreenUpdating = False
End With

Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
Set tbl = ws.ListObjects("Table1")

FirstRow = Range("Table1[Client]").Row

LastRow = tbl.Range.Cells(tbl.Range.Cells.Rows.Count, 1).Row

For i = LastRow - 2 To FirstRow Step -1
    Set rng = ws.Range(ws.Cells(i, 2), ws.Cells(i, 2).End(xlToRight))
    If WorksheetFunction.CountBlank(rng) = 4 Then
        ws.Rows(i).Delete
    End If
Next i

With Application
    .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    .ScreenUpdating = True
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Make sure the Sheet1, Table1 and table column Client exist or change the references in the code.

Comment: Now Im receiving 'application-defined or object-defined error on the code line that says 'firstrow = range("table1[client]:).row

Comment: Create a dummy workbook and on Sheet1 insert a table with default name Table1 and run the code and it will run without an issue. BTW make sure the table column named Client exists and it has no leading or trailing spaces.

Comment: Now I received a 'method 'range' of object_global'failed' for the code line - 
     FirstRow = Range("Table2, [Client]").Row

Comment: @n00b - why did you place a `,` between `Table2` and `[Client]`?

Comment: I will try removing it.

Comment: @YowE3K it did not effect it, still application or object defined error